# Remote Datasource and Remote Views + MVVM

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, telerik, datasource

I am trying to separate my Views and ViewModels in a Kendo Mobile app (ie. not MVC). I have a remote datasource in a ViewModel and cannot get it to work - I am sure it is something simple (I can't find a Kendo example that uses a Remote DataSource in a ViewModel - it is all inline. (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/mvvm/remote-binding.html, http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/datasource/overview)

It just shows this "function (e){var n=this;return e===t?n._data:(n._data=this._observe(e),n._ranges=[],n._addRange(n._data),n._total=n._data.length,n._process(n._data),t)}"  and not the actual data.

**games.html View**

```
<div id="tabstrip-home"
     data-role="view"
     data-title="Games"
     data-model="app.gamesService.viewModel">

    <ul class="games-list"               
         data-bind="source: gamesDataSource"
         data-template="template">
    </ul>

</div>

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
    <div class="product">
        <h3>#:ProductName#</h3>
        <p>#:kendo.toString(UnitPrice, "c")#</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

**games.js ViewModel**

```
(function (global) {
    var GamesViewModel, app = global.app = global.app || {};
 
    GamesViewModel = kendo.data.ObservableObject.extend({
                                                            gamesDataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                                                                                                           transport: {
                                                                    read: {
                                                                                                                   url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Products",
                                                                                                                   dataType: "jsonp"
                                                                                                               }
                                                                }
                                                                                                       })
                                                             
                                                        });
    app.gamesService = {
        viewModel: new GamesViewModel()
    };
})(window);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an example and managed to get this working, although the javascript is a little different. I'll have to read up on

```
(function (global) {
    var GamesViewModel,
        app = global.app = global.app || {};

    GamesViewModel = kendo.data.ObservableObject.extend({
        gamesDataSource: null,

        init: function () {
            var that = this,
                dataSource;

            kendo.data.ObservableObject.fn.init.apply(that, []);

            dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Products",
                        dataType: "jsonp"

                        //ProductID":1,"ProductName":"Chai","UnitPrice":18,"UnitsInStock":39,"Discontinued":false

                    }
                }
            });

            that.set("gamesDataSource", dataSource);
        }
    });

    app.gamesService = {
        viewModel: new GamesViewModel()
    };
})(window);
```

Comment: ps - I don't really understand the difference here - kendo.data.ObservableObject.extend   this 2nd bit of code seems to be extending the Init Event - I actually need to expose a Remote Datasource on another event (e.g. on the click of a button)